# How do I know which size class a constraint is for?

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uikit

I'm looking at a project and it has several greyed out constraints that are apparently for a different size class. If I only show constraints for the current size class, then constraints disappear.

Yet if I cycle through some of the device / orientation options, none of these constraints turn on.

How do I find out which size class a constraint is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Size Inspector when inspecting a Constraint, and look at the bottom to see where it is "Installed"

[image]

Comment: I think that my greyed out constraints are not actually used at all because they don't have an installed row for a size class.